# Is there any way in Firefox to match a specific XUL text node via standard CSS3 or any Mozilla-specific extensions?

Tags: css, firefox

I want to use CSS to match only certain labels in the Find Bar in the Firefox browser so that I can color them to meet my needs.

Using CSS3 **or any Mozilla-specific CSS extensions**, is there any way to specify a node that has specific a text string?

I'm okay if the solution only works within the XUL namespace, since that is my goal.

Comment: @timolawl Ugh.  Thanks for finding that.  My search came up nil before I wrote all that.  Let me change it up a bit...

Comment: @timolawl Thanks again for finding the other question.  I updated this one to include more specifics and options to differentiate it from other questions.

Comment: I made the same mistake on my very first question. Searched and searched, yet it ended up being a duplicate. I deleted it out of shame. Pretty sure it happens quite often :).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, not with plain CSS. You would need Javascript to do that.

If you want to solve your problem with plain CSS, you can add a data attribute to the element:

```
<ul>
    <li data-value="foo">foo</li>
    <li data-value="bar">bar</li>
    <li data-value="foo">foo</li>
    <li data-value="foo">foo</li>
    <li data-value="bar">bar</li>
</ul>
```

You're now able to select only nodes with `data-value="bar"` with the following CSS rule: `[data-value="bar"]`.

Comment: Thanks Fla.  I edited the question significantly while you were writing your thoughtful answer.  My apologies.  If you have any ideas to reflect the changes I made, I'm interested.  Thanks again.